# REGEX: Remove spaces between strings with one or two letters

Tags: python, regex, etl, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following original strings showed in the first columns of the following table:

```
Original String                  Parsed String                   Desired String
'W. & J. JOHNSON LMT.COM'       #W    J  JOHNSON LIMITED        #WJ JOHNSON LIMITED
'NORTH ROOF & WORKS CO. LTD.'   #NORTH ROOF   WORKS CO  LTD     #NORTH ROOF WORKS CO LTD
'DAVID DOE & CO., LIMITED'      #DAVID DOE   CO   LIMITED       #DAVID DOE CO LIMITED
'GEORGE TV & APPLIANCE LTD.'    #GEORGE TV   APPLIANCE LTD      #GEORGE TV APPLIANCE LTD 
'LOVE BROS. & OTHERS LTD.'      #LOVE BROS    OTHERS LTD        #LOVE BROS OTHERS LTD
'A. B. & MICHAEL CLEAN CO. LTD.'#A  B    MICHAEL CLEAN CO  LTD  #AB MICHAEL CLEAN CO LTD
'C.M. & B.B. CLEANER INC.'      #C M    B B  CLEANER INC        #CMBB CLEANER INC
```

Punctuation needs to be removed which I have done as follows:

```
def transform(word):
    word = re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Za-z])\'(?=[A-Za-z])[A-Z]|[^\w\s]|(.com|COM)',' ',word)
```

However, there is one last point which I have not been able to get. After removing punctuations I ended up with lots of spaces. How can I have a regular expression that put together initials and keep single spaces for regular words (no initials)?

Is this a bad approach to substitute the mentioned characters to get the desired strings?

Thanks for allowing me to continue learning :)

Comment: my bad, it is just one space. All words are separated by single space.

Comment: It looks like you are replacing all periods `.` and ampersands `&` with a blank space. I would do the cleaning in 3 separate steps: remove special characters, replace multiple spaces with a single space, then remove the space between each pair of single letters.

Comment: So logically, how does `A. B.` become `AB` and `C.M. & B.B.` become `CM BB` and not `CMBB`? But then `W. & J.` becomes `WJ`

Comment: does it make sense to replace `.` with nothing and `&` with a space?

Comment: @ctwheels that's correct, I check the logic and it has to be like you mentioned.

Comment: It depends whether this has to be highly performant or highly maintainable.
If I can afford it I'd go for readable / easy to understand and maintainable code.
Surprisingly the performance difference is not always that big. but of course you have to try.

Option 1.
use your regexp above as first step and perform a `rslt = " ".join(rslt.split())` to remove the white spaces.

Option 2
use your regexp as step 1 and to an re.sub as step 2. `rslt = re.sub("\s+", " ", rslt)`

you could use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's simpler to do this in parts. First, remove `.com` and any punctuation other than `space` or `&`. Then, remove a `space` or `&` surrounded by only one letter. Finally, replace any remaining sequence of `space` or `&` with a single space:

```
import re
strings = ['W. & J. JOHNSON LMT.COM',
'NORTH ROOF & WORKS CO. LTD.',
'DAVID DOE & CO., LIMITED',
'GEORGE TV & APPLIANCE LTD.',
'LOVE BROS. & OTHERS LTD.',
'A. B. & MICHAEL CLEAN CO. LTD.',
'C.M. & B.B. CLEANER INC.'
]

for s in strings:
    s = re.sub(r'\.COM|[^a-zA-Z& ]+', '', s, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
    s = re.sub(r'(?<=\b\w)\s*[ &]\s*(?=\w\b)', '', s)
    s = re.sub(r'\s*[& ]\s*', ' ', s)
    print s
```

Output

```
WJ JOHNSON LMT
NORTH ROOF WORKS CO LTD
DAVID DOE CO LIMITED
GEORGE TV APPLIANCE LTD
LOVE BROS OTHERS LTD
AB MICHAEL CLEAN CO LTD
CM BB CLEANER INC
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/UZK68493)

**Update**

This was written before the edit to the question changing the required result for the last data. Given the edit, the above code can be simplified to

```
for s in strings:
     s = re.sub(r'\.COM|[^a-zA-Z ]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)\s+(?!\w\w)', '', s, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
     print s
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/HQD65546)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I have ran your regex against all the database and it is quite impressive how is hitting the previous patterns. The execution time is 15 secs. However, there is just one patterns I am not able to include in regex which is hyphen between two words: `ALL-WEST GLASS`. Another patterns that was not matching was numbers and apostrophes, but I added that to have: `\.COM|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)\s+(?!\w\w)|''[A-Z]`

Comment: @JuanPerez Sorry about the missing bits - I was only able to work against the data you supplied. Have you resolved the hyphen issue? The current code would remove that, did you want to keep it?

Comment: I see that the current code removes the hyphen and put together the words. I was looking to keep it and add an external regex to treat just the hyphen to be replaced by space.

Comment: @JuanPerez you can modify the regex slightly to this `r'\.COM|[^a-zA-Z -]+|\s(?=&)|(?<!\w\w)(?:\s+|-)(?!\w\w)'` which will preserve a hyphen between words (and then later replace it with a space) See https://rextester.com/PKQ93755

Comment: not sure why hyphen is after the space? `[^a-zA-Z -]+`

Comment: by the way so far it is working removing the hyphen with space in the external regex.

Comment: @JuanPerez that is preventing that part of the regex from matching a hyphen. Because hyphen is special in a character class (to make a range e.g. A-Z) it needs to be either at the end of the class (as I have done) or escaped with backslash. The reason I did it this way was to allow for a hyphen which was not between words to be removed, so you don't end up with extra spaces in the output from that case.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this in regex alone won't be pretty and is not the best solution, yet, here it is! You're better off doing a multiple step approach. What I've done is identified all the cases that are possible and opted to find a solution where there's no replacement string since you're not always replacing the characters with spaces.

---

#### Rules

1. Non "Stacked" Abbreviations

   - These are locations like `A. B.` or `W. & J.`, but not `C.M. & B.B.`
   - I've identified these as locations where an abbreviation part (e.g. `A.`) exists before and after, but the latter is not followed by another alpha character
2. Preceding Space

   - These locations don't exist in your text but could if a space preceded a non-alpha character without a space following it (say at the end of a line)
   - We match the characters after the first space in these cases
3. Proceeding Space

   - These are locations like `&` and the dot in `J.`
   - We match the character before the last space in those examples
4. No Spaces

   - These are locations like `'LOVE` (the apostrophe in that string)
   - We only match the non-alpha-non-whitespace characters

---

#### Regex

An all-in-one regex that accomplishes this is as follows:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/b9lVGl/1)

```
(?<=\b[a-z])[^a-z]+(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))|(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *| *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *(?= )|(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)(?! )
```

Works as follows (broken into each alternation):

- `(?<=\b[a-z])[^a-z]+(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))` matches non-alpha characters between `A.` and `B.` but not `A.` and `B.B`

  - `(?<=\b[a-z])` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is an alpha character and assert a word boundary position to its left
  - `[^a-z]+` match any non-alpha character one or more times
  - `(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))` positive lookahead ensuring the following exists

    - `[a-z]\b` match any alpha character and assert a word boundary position to its right
    - `(?![^a-z][a-z])` negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a non-alpha character followed by an alpha character
- `(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *` ensures a space precedes, then matches any spaces, `.com` or any non-word-non-whitespace characters one or more times, then any spaces

  - `(?<= )` positive lookbehind ensuring a space precedes
  - `*` match any number of spaces
  - `(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)` match `.com` and ensure a non-word character follows, or match any non-word-non-whitespace character one or more times
  - `*` match any number of spaces
- `*(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *(?= )` matches any spaces, `.com` or any non-word-non-whitespace characters one or more times, then any spaces, then ensures a space follows

  - Same as previous but instead of the positive lookbehind at the beginning, there's a positive lookahead at the end
- `(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)(?! )` matches `.com` or any non-alpha-non-whitespace characters one or more times ensuring no spaces surround it

  - Same as previous two options but uses negative lookbehind and negative lookahead

---

#### Code

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##dZFNb4IwGIDP9le8ehjtZL3sZmYMlk5wQA0QPYhLZOJGMoEUzLLF/85aNJlZtlPb93nej7bVZ/NWFvdtmx@qUjYgM4TqRubFaw1jWKPewFhRuIE5hblwgkgE4PkxZcI3BqamgQhjB0IhHpW1EuFTBExQ8GKbXgzbWro22IIrQSETPNd3Y25f8IyLcMYhXipsLRaeawWMX@d7YslhGopIzyFih4fRNbYoTDXxXeZY3APmcSv4PQOjvnamVKmdwENwA6Yw2iAk1VVlRl/KQ5W/Z1gaePIwTtL19u5rQ9bPehniybg7Jyme9M@xMycnbQOBWzwZJbpIkp46Iak3QxU@/UtUTejS@0D@VFQrIIaph3Nn6qU5syJOENple2jktqj3pTzgj1LuyAj1ZNYcZaHl@phiaYKhUjuIkBKhhryAy@cqvVKbBv@UqQlp228)

```
import re

strings = [
    "'W. & J. JOHNSON LMT.COM'",
    "'NORTH ROOF & WORKS CO. LTD.'",
    "'DAVID DOE & CO., LIMITED'",
    "'GEORGE TV & APPLIANCE LTD.'",
    "'LOVE BROS. & OTHERS LTD.'",
    "'A. B. & MICHAEL CLEAN CO. LTD.'",
    "'C.M. & B.B. CLEANER INC.'"
]

r = re.compile(r'(?<=\b[a-z])[^a-z]+(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))|(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *| *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *(?= )|(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)(?! )', re.IGNORECASE)

def transform(word):
    return re.sub(r, '', word)

for s in strings:
    print(transform(s))
```

Outputs:

```
WJ JOHNSON LMT
NORTH ROOF WORKS CO LTD
DAVID DOE CO LIMITED
GEORGE TV APPLIANCE LTD
LOVE BROS OTHERS LTD
AB MICHAEL CLEAN CO LTD
CM BB CLEANER INC
```

---

### Edit

Using a callback, you can extend this logic to include special cases as mentioned in a comment below my answer to match specific cases and have conditional replacements.

These special cases include:

- `FONTAINE'S` to `FONTAINE`
- `PREMIUM-FIT AUTO` to `PREMIUM FIT AUTO`
- `62325 W.C.` to `62325 WC`

I added a new alternation to the regex: `(\b[\'-]\b(?:[a-z\d] )?)` to capture `'S` or `-` between letters (also `-S` or similar) and replace it with a space using the callback (if the capture group exists).

I still suggest using multiple regular expressions to accomplish this, but I wanted to show that it is possible with a single pattern.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##fZLBbuIwEIbP9VNMe1jbLVjaVt0DKopMYsBsEqPEhQOhUtmGbiQgkRMOrXh31qZBqlZqlYs13ze/x3aqt@Zvubs7HottVZoGTI5Q3Zhi91pDHxbo4grPGfyACYOJGsepiiGMNPNVhK86jsYq0WNIlBpaa66S3yn4ikGoA9YaAZ/JAAIlrGBRB0IZSS2CFo@ESkYC9MxiPp2Gkse@@NwfqpmAQaJSN4fSY5GknzFnMHAkkv6YixD8UPD4/xl8FjlnwKx6EkQCMvbPeKhizWUscArTRETyMeoOpQb@qBX8ur27vYc5czJaImTsvZic/Sm3VbHJicHEe@hnq8Vz9z17WdLF08fihnj9tpatiHd5rp89enB9QOGaeL3MxWWrQytl9fLGgsM3zKaDjbD7Zrh72qHXJgP1TtmXQL/ottMAxR13Cjmy7yd8ngqK0Eu@trVqQ7a0hy5M3uzNDrD9ijVs2asp9xX5SSHf1DlgjNC6NFBDsYP2h7FNlV00xLB6vyIuqgM1pcfjPw)

```
import re

strings = [
    "'W. & J. JOHNSON LMT.COM'",
    "'NORTH ROOF & WORKS CO. LTD.'",
    "'DAVID DOE & CO., LIMITED'",
    "'GEORGE TV & APPLIANCE LTD.'",
    "'LOVE BROS. & OTHERS LTD.'",
    "'A. B. & MICHAEL CLEAN CO. LTD.'",
    "'C.M. & B.B. CLEANER INC.'",
    "'FONTAINE'S PREMIUM-FIT AUTO 62325 W.C.'"
]

r = re.compile(r'(?<=\b[a-z\d])[^a-z\d]+(?=[a-z\d]\b(?![^a-z\d][a-z\d]))|(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\d\s]+) *| *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\d\s]+) *(?= )|(\b[\'-]\b(?:[a-z\d] )?)|(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\d\s]+)(?! )', re.IGNORECASE)

def repl(m):
    return ' ' if m.group(1) else ''

for s in strings:
    print(r.sub(repl, s))
```

Comment: is it not supposed to be added as this: `text=re.sub(r'(?<=\b[a-z])[^a-z]+(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))|(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *| *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *(?= )|(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)(?! )','' , text)`

Comment: @JuanPerez something like that, I can't test at the moment, but I can get back to you later and confirm. Add `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: re.sub(r'(?<=\b[a-z])[^a-z]+(?=[a-z]\b(?![^a-z][a-z]))|(?<= ) *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *| *(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+) *(?= )|(?<! )(?:\.com\b|[^a-z\s]+)(?! )','',text,0,re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: I have tried the remaining patterns in database, but I am getting problems when the word is including apostrophe. For instance, the word `FONTAINE'S` should be `FOUNTAINE`. In addition, I have some words that are including hyphens such as `PREMIUM-FIT AUTO` should be `PREMIUM FIT AUTO`. Finally, I have words starting with numbers such as `62325 W.C.` which should be `62325 WC`. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: @JuanPerez with those cases in mind, a single regex will never work since you can't replace with nothing and replace certain locations with spaces (unless you use a callback). With that in mind, you can use a callback as I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest I could get it with one regex pattern:

`\.COM|(?<![A-Z]{2}) (?![A-Z]{2})|[.&,]| (?>)&`

Basically, it removes characters that fit 3 criteria:

1. Literal ".COM"
2. Spaces that are not preceded or followed by 2 capital letters
3. Dots, ampersands, and commas, regardless of where they appear
4. Spaces followed by ampersands

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EMHxq9/2

Comment: I have ran your regex in the database and it is matching all the patterns. The query lasted 16 secs executing a query as select regex_replace() from .. Your regex is very simple and finds all the patterns :)  The final version look like this `\.COM|(?<![A-Z0-9]{2}) (?![A-Z]{2})|[.&,()]|''[A-Z]` Thanks for your help :)